# Angular form array bound using a *ngFor (for loop) allows input, one character at a time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, angular-forms

**This is the input field bound using formBuilder**

```
hobbies: formBuilder.array([
    ['', Validators.required],
])
```

I think the problem is with my form binding in the template. Is this approach incorrect? What is the proper way to bind a Form Array to the template?

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let hobby of myForm.get('hobbies').value; let i = index;">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="{{ i }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{ i }}` refer to each letters of "hobby", that's why you get this.

Try `{{ hobby[i] }}` instead